# How to anti-alias clip() edges in html5 canvas under Chrome Windows?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-canvas, clip

I'm using the clip() function on a canvas.

Results:
[image: using canvas clip in various browsers]

As you can see the chrome version has horrible jaggies / aliasing along the edges. How do I fix this?

Code to reproduce:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZRA76/ :

```
<canvas id="test" width="300" height="300"></canvas>​

<script type="text/javascript">
    cv = document.getElementById("test");
    ctx = cv.getContext("2d");

    var im = new Image();
    im.onload = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(110, 110, 100, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.drawImage(im, 0, 0);
    }
    im.src = "http://placekitten.com/300/300";
</script>
```

Comment: I ran into this problem as well. What I did was to draw a circle at the same place as the image, behind it, with 1 or 2 px larger radius. Keep the color similar and there you go, "anti aliased" image clip.

Answer (score 26):

If you're doing complex, layered drawing, you can use globalCompositeOperation to emulate clipping in a second, scratch canvas. You can then use drawImage to copy the scratch canvas back into the original canvas. I can't guarantee the performance of this approach, but it's the only way I know to get what you want.

```
//set-up - probably only needs to be done once
var scratchCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
scratchCanvas.width = 100;
scratchCanvas.height = 100;
var scratchCtx = scratchCanvas.getContext('2d');


//drawing code
scratchCtx.clearRect(0, 0, scratchCanvas.width, scratchCanvas.height);

scratchCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'; //default

//Do whatever drawing you want. In your case, draw your image.
scratchCtx.drawImage(imageToCrop, ...);


//As long as we can represent our clipping region as a single path, 
//we can perform our clipping by using a non-default composite operation.
//You can think of destination-in as "write alpha". It will not touch
//the color channel of the canvas, but will replace the alpha channel.
//(Actually, it will multiply the already drawn alpha with the alpha
//currently being drawn - meaning that things look good where two anti-
//aliased pixels overlap.)
//
//If you can't represent the clipping region as a single path, you can
//always draw your clip shape into yet another scratch canvas.

scratchCtx.fillStyle = '#fff'; //color doesn't matter, but we want full opacity
scratchCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
scratchCtx.beginPath();
scratchCtx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
scratchCtx.closePath();
scratchCtx.fill();


//Now that we have a nice, cropped image, we can draw it in our
//actual canvas. We can even draw it over top existing pixels, and
//everything will look great!

ctx.drawImage(scratchCanvas, ...);
```

The reason that we do this in a scratch canvas is that destination-in is a pretty destructive operation. If you had already drawn some things into the main canvas (perhaps you put down a nice gradient in the background), and then wanted to draw a clipped image, the clipping circle would also clip out everything you had already drawn. Of course, if your particular situation is simpler (maybe ALL you want to draw is a clipped image), then you can forego the scratch canvas.

You can play around with the different clipping modes on [my demo page](http://balefrost.org/programming/CanvasComposite/index.html). The bottom row (with the gradients) is not too useful to you, but the top row (with the circle and square) is much more relevant.

**edit**

Whoops, I accidentally [forked your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balefrost/ZRA76/82/) to demonstrate the technique.

Answer (score 12):

My fix for this is to draw a thin (2px) white stroke at the same radius after drawing the image. It covers up the aliasing nicely and looks fine across browsers.

Comment: I've been struggling with this today for more than an hour, such a simple and amazing solution :)

Comment: YES, THIS, CLEVER, <3!

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same issue with Chrome and clip().

In my circumstance I achieved better browser compatibility by setting the canvas globalCompositeOperation.

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
```

So draw your shape, a circle in this case. Then switch to 'source-atop' and draw your kitten image.

Note, this is a quick fix for basic drawing and assumes a blank canvas. Previous canvas drawing will affect your clip.

Comment: This solution performs very well, thank you. One arc for the clip and one arc for the stroke. Simple. I believe the scratch canvas solution is much too complicated and slow for this problem unless you have some issue with NOT wanting the stroke.

Comment: I was able to apply this, plus the "back-canvas" technique, to reduce a nasty jagged edge when I was running a video through canvas: http://codepen.io/paceaux/pen/egLOeR

Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

from the answers on [Can I turn off antialiasing on an HTML <canvas> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element) it appears that it is browser specific. It is even an active [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7508) on the google code chromium project. Sorry, but it looks like you're out of luck for now.

Comment: Now, the bug fix is in development status in [chrome dashboard](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4871530282483712).
As written in [Issues](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422984), othere browsers(IE, Firefox, Safari) `clip()` are antialiased.

Answer (score -1):

Use svg clip. Works like a charm but is not so convenient to use.