# A smooth circle in Html5

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a circle with a canvas in HTML5. I use an example from w3schools, but the result is ugly, not smooth. Is it possible to have a smooth circle ? (I tried this with Chrome and IE9)

The code I use :

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(125,120,100,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

=> http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_path2 : the original example
=> http://jsfiddle.net/jPeKk/ : my try, bigger

Comment: Are you open to using css to build your circle instead?  http://davidwalsh.name/css-circles

Comment: My aim is to build shapes that a user can edit (scale, rotation, ...). If the solution is to avoid the canvas, why not, but I'm a bit surprised with this result, it's a so basic feature...

Answer (score 0):

On chrome, this is a known issue that has been discussed here - [Can I turn off antialiasing on an HTML <canvas> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element)

and here - [How to anti-alias clip() edges in html5 canvas under Chrome Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536257/how-to-anti-alias-clip-edges-in-html5-canvas-under-chrome-windows)

Try

```
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled=true;
```

to make your line smoother.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I didn't see a difference : http://jsfiddle.net/CSgGJ/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that works for me (though I think it's more of a hack than a proper solution) is to draw a line around the circle with the same color. For some reason this is going to be very smooth.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = '#775599';
context.fill();

context.beginPath();
context.arc(200, 200, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = '#775599';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = '#775599';
context.stroke();
```