# Canvas Circles Draw Inconsistently

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

For example, drawing a black circle followed by a white circle of the same radius in the same location leaves behind a grey residue. I'm assuming it's not drawing the circles the same, per pixel, each time.

I wish to have a circle move around in a canvas but in order to do this I will need to overwrite the circle before drawing it in its new location.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="960" height="540" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "white";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.strokeStyle = "white";
context.stroke();
```

Comment: To do animation on a web canvas you usually just redraw all the moving parts (buffering is already included: nothing is displayed until you end your event handling).

Comment: Interesting.  You could add `context.lineWidth = 2;` before the last `context.stroke()`, but that seems silly.

Comment: I see. Redrawing everything per frame seems better anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to redraw the background every time.

```
function drawBg() {
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

drawBg();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();

drawBg();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.strokeStyle = "white";
context.stroke();
```

I did some research into this phenomenon. I think the cause is anti-aliasing.

1. [Can I turn off antialiasing on an HTML <canvas> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element)
2. [How to anti-alias clip() edges in html5 canvas under Chrome Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536257/how-to-anti-alias-clip-edges-in-html5-canvas-under-chrome-windows)

It seems you can't draw pixel-perfect hard-edged circles on the html canvas with `arc()` and vector graphics.

Comment: Does this mean that if I have multiple circles moving around I will need to erase the entire canvas and redraw each circle each time?

Comment: No, if you have more circles moving around then first you draw the background then you draw all the circles. But you will have this phenomena though.

Comment: I see. So I'll do this drawBg each frame. It's how I should have been doing it from the start. For some reason I was going to manage circles independent which is messy. Your way fixes it. Thank you for your help