# Replace javascript context.arc with an image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have this code that draw a circle on the canvas.

```
        create: function(){
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.fill();
        }
```

Is it possible to replace the circles with images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas - Fill circle with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276048/html5-canvas-fill-circle-with-image).

There's a good clipping example on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing#A_clip_example