# How can I add an image inside a circle in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to insert this image

```
var img=new Image();
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/desert1.jpg";
```

Into the circle, that I'm drawing with this function

```
function drawBall() {
    //ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-in';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,20);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Here's what the canvas currently looks like:

[image: exemplary rendering]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276048/html5-canvas-fill-circle-with-image

Comment: Duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas - Fill circle with image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276048/html5-canvas-fill-circle-with-image)

Comment: While the ultimate goal is the same, I disagree with these dupes CV since here it seems more like  an incomprehension of how gCO works (which is btw a way better way of doing than the answers provided in the dupe.)

Answer (score 0):

globalCompositeOperation mode `source-over` is the default gCO mode, which draws new content over the existing one.
You need to set it to `destination-in` **after** you've drawn something on the canvas, so only the pixels where both the new pixels and the already painted ones will overlap, stay.

```js
var img=new Image();
img.onload = drawBall;
img.src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg";

function drawBall() {
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    c.width = this.width;
    c.height = this.height;
  
    // default gCO is source-over
    ctx.drawImage(img,-250,-200, img.width*.7, img.height*.7);
    // now we change the gCO
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-in';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    // reset to default
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
    // closePath is useless here
    //ctx.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: sorry I've not shown whole code , anyway this runs perfect but there is one problem I want image to move around. in arc(x,y...) i was changing x and y and it was good but now only background is changing .

Comment: @Cotne you need to also change x and y values passed to `drawImage`